# Handling Core apps of android in phonegap

Tags: cordova

**Can we make changes to the core apps of android using phonegap by the means of plugin in phonegap?**

Comment: core apps include email client, SMS program, calendar, maps, browser, contacts, and others..http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't make changes to the core applications -- they're all written in native code, and any code you write can only access whatever public `Intents` they've registered.